# MongoDB consistency with safe mode off

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, consistency

Help me understand what level of consistency I can expect with MongoDB in this situation.

We are running a replica set with the `consistency` flag in Mongoid set to `strong` meaning that reads only go to the master.  But the `safe` configuration is defaulted to `false` so write operations return immediately.

Assuming there aren't any errors, if a client app inserts a new large document and then quickly tries to read it in another thread, are we guaranteed to get the document back?  Or do we need to turn `safe` mode on to ensure that level of consistency?

Comment: The same consistency as ever will exist db end, it is all about the acknowledgement level on the application as to whether there was an error performing the operation or not, turning off "safe mode" causes a fire and forget method to making database calls. As to reading, you might need to wait for the operation to finish, hmm depends though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write and then subsequently read from a primary, you will *not* always get a consistent result. It matters whether you are on the same connection or not. If you are on the same connection, you do not need *safe*. If you are **not** on the same connection, you need *safe*.

Comment: Even if they're on different connections, and the system is bogged down with write contention?  Could the write command get queued up by the global lock and the read go through first?  Or what about yielding?  The docs say a write will yield its lock if it causes a page fault.